# Can I recognize beacons when my phone Bluetooth is turned off in the Android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Currently, Android apps recognize beacons and send and receive data.
Is there a way to recognize beacons and send and receive data even when Bluetooth is turned off?
Is it possible to turn on the Bluetooth, send and receive data, and turn it off again when the beacons are detected?

Answer (score 1):

**Bluetooth must be turned on to detect beacons on Android.**  However, by declaring the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission **an app can programmatically turn Bluetooth on and off**.  Since this permission is required to scan for beacons, anyway, it is easy to do.  So, yes, you can turn Bluetooth on, scan for beacons, then turn it back off when done.

In practice, the reasons you might want to do this are rare, as Bluetooth being on uses minimal battery and system resources.   Possible motivations for doing this might be:

1. The user has turned Bluetooth off.  An app needing to use Bluetooth temporarily might turn it on temporarily, then turn it back off to respect user wishes.
2. Turning Bluetooth off and back on can sometimes clear a bad state in the Bluetooth stack.
3. There are some (debatable) privacy advantages of keeping Bluetooth off.  Turning it on only briefly might help preserve some of these privacy advantages.